# Sketch the graph of an integral function

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to sketch the graph of $F(x)$

$F(x)=\int_0^x te^{(-\frac{1}{t^2})} dt$

How I can sketch the graph of an integral that I didn't know?

Comment: Should the integral be $\int_0^x$ instead of $\int_0^\infty$?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I think you the infinity sign should be changed by x. You can calculate the value of the integral by a numerical method (Simpson for instance) and for different value of x. then it can easily be sketched by connecting the points

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry.